# How to change the label color of a react-native-material-textfield?

Tags: react-native

```
<TextField
              label={"Full Name"}
              autoFocus={true}
              lineWidth={3}
              activeLineWidth={3}
              baseColor={"red"}
              labelTextStyle={{color:"grey"}}
              textColor={"grey"}`enter code here`
            />
```

Currently labelTextStyle={{color:"black"}} does not work

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the library "react-native-material-textfield", then to change the color of the label you need to use 'baseColor' property. By using this property, I resolved my issue to change the color of the label. Below is my code snippet,

```js
    <TextField
          label = 'USERNAME/MOBILENO'
          tintColor = '#51bc8a'
          value = {username}
          textColor = '#51bc8a'
          baseColor = '#FFFFFF'
          onChangeText = { (username) => this.setState({ username }) }
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `labelTextStyle` prop does work properly. Check out [this example Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pziegler/react-native-material-text-field-example). Your issue here is that this prop **does not** control the `color` of the label itself. That gets controlled by the `baseColor` (when the field is not active) or by the `tintColor` prop (when the field is active). `textColor` controls the color of the text input, but not the label.

Comment: yes Parker u are correct ....I want to control the label color and not apply the baseColor when the field is not active...how can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly. According to material design guidelines, the label color and the underline color for the text input **must be the same** in all states (base, error, active). Are you saying you want the label color to be different from the underline color? In that case, you may need to roll your own. What are the exact colors you want for the label and underline in all states?

Comment: if there is no data in the textinput it should be red and once the data is entered /is activethen it should become green

Comment: Does this fit your needs? https://snack.expo.io/@pziegler/react-native-material-text-field-example